# How can i determine which of my product's .net assemblies are registered, when i have several on my pc?

Tags: c#, .net, com, bho, regasm

I have the code for various versions of a software product I work on on my machine. The product includes one or more assemblies that are registered for com interop. How can I determine which one is currently registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the GUID of your assembly, look under `HKCR\CLSID\{your guid}\InprocServer32`.  The `Assembly` key will have a value including the version.

If you only have the ProgId, you can just search the registry for that string which will tell you the GUID.